# CBCentralManager:didDiscoverPeripheral, is there the concept of the discovered item not being seen?

Tags: objective-c, bluetooth, core-bluetooth, cbcentralmanager

working on a bluetooth implementation and am using didDiscoverPeripheral to populate a list.  But, if the device is turned off or is moved away want to be able to remove the device from my list.  Anyone know of a delegate or way to track items no longer valid?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There is no in-built functionality. You can build it yourself by using the allow duplicates key and keeping a time stamp with each discovered peripheral. Fire a timer periodically and look for "old" peripheral's and remove them from the list.